# any scripting language can read AJAX/Java Script? (linux)

Tags: ajax, linux, web-scraping

is there any way I can **scrape** web pages that uses **AJAX**?

by using something like ruby + mechanize on **linux** server that **doesn't have monitor** attached (linode.com for example)

http://watir.com/ would be a solution but I guess not applicable to linode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/). It can do testing without a monitor -- by using the HTMLUnit backend. It handles quite a lot of JavaScript, including AJAX. I use it to scrape several pages and have built several tests of AJAX with it.

You can also run TestPlan with a browser if you want. This gives you the best of both worlds: develop tests and visually see what is happening, and then switch to the display-less mode.